# MongoDB Count Items in array by name

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have documents like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b3ced158735f1196d73a743"),
    "cid" : 1,
    "foo" : [
        {
            "k" : "sport",
            "v" : "climbing"
        },
        {
            "k" : "sport",
            "v" : "soccer"
        },
        {
            "k" : "sport",
            "v" : "soccer"
        }
    ]
}
```

This Query just return the documents which contains a soccer field.

```
db.coll.find({foo:{$elemMatch:{ v: "soccer"}} }, {"foo.$" : 1,cid:1})
```

returns:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b3ced158735f1196d73a743"), "cid" : 1, "node" : [ { "k" : "sport", "v" : "climbing" } ] }
```

But I want to know, how many soccer-Elements are in each returned document. How can I count them?

Comment: Just wanted to know if I got your question.
You expect output : 2 ?
Am I right?

Comment: Yeah, cid and count.
There are a lot of documents like this. And I need for example:
{cid: 1,count:4},
{cid:3,count: 2}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below query to [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) and [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) the filtered array to count no of matching occurrences.

```
db.coll.aggregate([
  {"$project":{
    "cid":1,
    "count":{
      "$size":{
        "$filter":{
          "input":"$foo",
          "cond":{"$eq":["$$this.v","soccer"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: Cool, but how can I just return fields with count > 0?

Comment: You can add match stage after project. Something like `{"$match":{"count":{"$gt":0}}}`

Answer (score 2):

```
db.coll.aggregate(

    // Pipeline
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $match: {
                foo: {
                    $elemMatch: {
                        v: 'soccer'
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        // Stage 2
        {
            $unwind: {
                path: '$foo'
            }
        },

        // Stage 3
        {
            $project: {
                cid: 1,
                count: {
                    $cond: {
                        if: {
                            $eq: ['$foo.v', 'soccer']
                        },
                        then: {
                            $sum: 1
                        },
                        else: 0
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        // Stage 4
        {
            $group: {
                _id: '$cid',
                total_count: {
                    $sum: '$count'
                }
            }
        }

    ]



);
```